# Find $\sum_{r=n+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)$

Tags: summation

Find $$\sum_{r=n+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)-\sum_{r=1}^{n} \left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)\;.$$

I found that: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$$ however, I am not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?
Many thanks

Comment: Take the sum from $r=n$ to $r=N$ and let $N\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: @Tuvasbien Isn't this a telescoping series?

Comment: With the result for the finite sum you are almost finished. Take the limit now

Comment: @77and33is100: The limit of the finite sum is not what’s wanted here.

Comment: @Tuvasbien, I’m not sure I follow

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  r_n  = \sum\limits_{r = n + 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}
{r} - \frac{1}
{{r + 1}}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}
{r} - \frac{1}
{{r + 1}}} \right)}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left( {\frac{1}
{r} - \frac{1}
{{r + 1}}} \right)}  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = 1 - \left( {1 - \frac{1}
{{n + 1}}} \right) = \frac{1}
{{n + 1}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Moreover
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } r_n  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sum\limits_{r = n + 1}^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}
{r} - \frac{1}
{{r + 1}}} \right)}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}
{{n + 1}} = 0
$$
as it must be with the $n-th$ remainder of a convergent series as $n \to +\infty$